# how to disable pop out animation of selected label in bottom navigation view android?

Tags: android, animation, popup, bottomnavigationview

I want to remove the popup animation from the selected option of a bottom navigation view.
I already removed the label and shift mode animation from my bottom navigation view using view helper class.

P.S Don't want to use any third party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"`

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: it is a xml attribute for bottom navigation view tag. but it is supported from API 28.